Solaris 10: extended attributes, how to create it?
Some Solaris 10 commands (ls, find..) support extended attributes.
With runat is possible to copy and list extended attributes. But how to create/insert an extended attribute in a file? On Linux we have chattr (chattr +i...chattr +m¹). On Solaris 10?
Thanks
1 DON'T TEST IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT THEY DID!

Solution found.
man runat

The extended attributes on Solaris 10 are completely different from Linux way. For example: is possible to associate a file to another file (maybe contain a description or some notes).
For example, associate to file.2 (empty) the contents of  /tmp/attrdata as attr.1
vim /tmp/attrdata

bla bla!
runat file.2 cp /tmp/attrdata attr.1  

Find found the file with attribute extended
find . -xattr
./file.2

to show the contents of attr.1
runat file.2 cat attr.1      
bla bla!

For other and more info
man fsattr
man runat

